# PHP accessing protected properties of an object from a static method

Tags: php, class, object, access-modifiers

Not sure if this is even a question. My understanding of protected/private properties and methods is that they can only be accessed from within the class. I have a static method which is sort of a quick method for saving an object to a database. I creating the object from within the static method and setting properties through setter functions. One property however has no setter and yet, I am still able to access it. I have a class that looks something like this:

```
class Person {

   protected $name;
   protected $email;
   protected $created;

   //set name
   public function set_name( $name ) {
       $this->name = $name;
   }

   //set email
   public function set_email( $email ) {
       $this->email = $email;
   }

   //add new person
   static function add( $data ) {

       $person = new Person;
       $person->set_name( $data['name'] );
       $person->set_email( $data['email'] );

       //set created date
       $person->created = date('Y-m-d h:ia', time());

       //save to db
       $db->add($data);

       return $person;

   }

}
```

Implementation looks something like this:

```
$person = Person::add(array(
   'name' => 'Bob Barker',
   'email' => 'bob@thepriceisright.com'
));
```

This code works. By works I mean that the created date get set successfully. Why?

Comment: Isn't your `add` method just another way to write a constructor?

Comment: Sure. Just a different approach. The class has many more uses throughout the application, so I choose to keep my method for saving to the DB separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protected properties can be modified by code within the class, not just from instances of that class.

Comment: Even when the method is static? This seems like a bug.

Comment: If you think of the point of encapsulation being that all of the logic for operating on the class' data lies within the class itself, this makes sense. Static methods are still defined within the class, and we can assume that a class knows how to operate on instances of itself. That's my take anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're setting it within the class. The setters are often used for setting the variables from outside from the class, such as Person::set_name('Bob Barker'). But if you tried Person->created = date(), it should fail.

Comment: I agree. It should fail. It does not. I can successfully set the created property on the object from within the static method.

Comment: No, the static method is within the class, so it can access the variables in the class. The variables are only protected from being accessed from OUTSIDE of the class. The Person->created I referenced would be from outside of the class implementation, below the $person = Person::add(array(... line

Comment: Ok. I misunderstood you. Makes sense.